# WPF DataGridRow custom style is dismissed when the Datagrid looses focus

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, highlight

In a scenario of a WPF form with multiple data grids, I have been (unsuccessfully) trying to conditionally change specific rows (background) color, which effect would signify to the user a optically detectable circumstance.

During trials although I have been able to set the (background) color correctly either by the use of **Data triggers** and bindings or by handling the **LoadingRow event**, the row style is getting dismissed when the grid controls lose focus.

As some people suggested the only way to by-pass this is by using the **System.HighlightBrush** which indeed works : despite the lost of focus, the rows of interest retain their style.

If I follow the aforementioned technique, is there a way to change the color of the HighlightBrush  to something other than the standard system default light blue one?

Answer (score 0):

Define your own brushes for `HighlightBrushKey` and `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` and put them in the `Resources` dictionary of the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I'll give it a go and come back to you about it @mm8.
Many thanks i!